# What is the difference between MACTripleDES and TripleDES?

Tags: encryption, implementation, mac, des, terminology

I was asked to encrypt/decrypt a string using MACTripleDES. Is there any difference between *MACTripleDES* and *TripleDES*? If, where exactly is the difference between both?

Comment: You mean [this thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.mactripledes(v=vs.110).aspx)? If so, [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533604/mactripledes-in-php) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks @IlmariKaronen, i've seen the msdn but the example showing to encrypt/decrypt the file not string.

Comment: That would be a valid question on [so], but not here. (Or you could just look at the documentation, and specifically the `ComputeHash(Byte[])` method). Also, you cannot "encrypt" or "decrypt" anything with a MAC; that's not what they're for.

Comment: Cross-posted on Stack Overflow: [How to encrypt decrypt string using MACTripleDES?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34660907/1816580)

Answer (score 6):

[Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is a [block cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6099/what-is-a-block-cipher).  (Specifically, it's a variant of the old [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) block cipher with better security, but several times lower performance.)  You can use it to encrypt small blocks of data (64 bits = 8 bytes, for Triple DES), but what it's *really* useful for is as a building block for other cryptographic schemes, such as [stream encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) or [message authentication codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MACs).

[MACTripleDES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.mactripledes(v=vs.110).aspx) is, apparently, a class in the Microsoft .NET framework that provides *some kind of* a MAC using Triple DES.  The documentation doesn't actually seem to say which MAC construction it uses, but [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533604/mactripledes-in-php/10543224#10543224) implies that it's classic [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC).

Note that raw CBC-MAC is not, by itself, secure for variable-length messages.  To make it secure, you need to use one of the techniques described in the linked Wikipedia article (prepending the length to the message, encrypting the output with a different key, or using a separate MAC key for each message length), or use a more modern MAC algorithm like [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) instead.  (You may also wish to consider using a more modern cipher with a larger key and block size and better performance than Triple DES, such [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).)